# How to read cell data from online version of Excel (sharepoint.com)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, sharepoint

I have few excel sheets created online and it is currently accessible via sharepoint.com domain name (Eg:- - *https://ORG_NAME.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/personal/NAME/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B068129EC-0652-453C-A2DB-89922E38228B%7D&file=Book.xlsx*)

Now i need to read the contents of the excel file from my React based SPA. I have already implemented similar functionality for Google Sheets using **google-sheets-mapper**. Can you please suggest any library for reading form sahrepoint.com? I did few research but didn't find anything useful.

Thank you.